# ModuleNotFoundError: but only appears when I start the debugger in pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Sorry - I have read all the similar issues among the posts but none of them solved my issue.

I am getting the below error when I try to open the debugger in pycharm(the app is working on a local server otherwise):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.forms'; '**main**' is
>   not a package

my project structure: 
[see my project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi3T3.png%C5%B1)

in my views.py under the app1 folder I need to reference a form class from the same directory:

```
from .forms import RestaurantForm
```

if I try it without the dot, but I get another error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

UPDATE: 
the path of the project is: 
C:\Users\Tamas\Desktop\django_website_project\project
while the path (python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)") is: 
['','C:\Users\Tamas\Desktop\django_website_project\venv\Scripts\python37.zip', 
'C:\Users\Tamas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs', 
'C:\Users\Tamas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib', 
'C:\Users\Tamas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37', 
'C:\Users\Tamas\Desktop\django_website_project\venv', 
'C:\Users\Tamas\Desktop\django_website_project\venv\lib\site-packages',
'C:\Users\Tamas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages']

Comment: What is `main` here in your project directory? What is the `PYTHON_PATH`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I add it to the edit section of the question. Thanks